# If NASA is going to capture an asteroid with a spacecraft, wouldn't a UFO be able to manuever a celestial body?

Tags: solar-system, asteroids, nasa, identify-this-object

[This article](http://www.space.com/20606-nasa-asteroid-capture-mission-images.html) got me thinking If NASA is going to use our primitive space exploration technology to capture an asteroid wouldn't an Extra Terrestrial species have used UFO's to maneuver celestial bodies?
They clearly would have come across this problem along time ago and the videos of UFO's levitating and vectoring themselves demonstrates they operate on similar applied electromagnetic forces that the celestial bodies use to maneuver themselves around in solar systems.
Couldn't they maneuver meteors, asteroids, possibly even speed the advance of collisions developing protoplanets and move moons into orbits with planets?
Maybe they build solar systems to live in they way earthlings build housing developments?

Comment: Moons and planets are _much_ heavier than asteroids. Also, I guess it would be hard to find suitable materials

Comment: Since they would know how to transition the vehicle between star systems it may be able to replicate forces of stars or stronger astronomic objects thereby making the planet or moon's weight negligible.

Comment: If you have a question about the technology they plan to use I would ask here:http://space.stackexchange.com/ . Otherwise, I believe it belongs here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it it not about the subject of astronomy as defined in the [Help Center](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming

- there are extraterrestrial space travelers
- those travelers have technologies we know nothing of
- those technologies we know nothing of allow "levitation" and
  "vectoring themselves" with "electromagnetic forces."

Asking what they would do if they existed and if they had capabilities is really the realm of science fiction. There can be no good answer to your question at this time. Maybe later we'll know, maybe never.

Answer (score 3):

One of a million possible answers:

An advanced civilization wouldn't do this without need.
If necessary, they would use [gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitation) instead of [magnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetism), since magnetism acts differently on different kind of matter, gravity is much better suited.

They would exploit the [chaotic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) behaviour of [n-body systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem) like planetary systems mainly governed by gravity, and find out which distortion of minimal intervention would return the desired result.

They would know the need long time in advance, hence be able to act, when there is still enough time to get the desired result with a reasonably small effort.